# Oddity about declared multi-core CPU power?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, core

I am having quite a hard time in understanding the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on two 4-core Linux boxes here at work. Basically I am running algorithm experiments on the two machines (let's name them `red` and `blue`); on the average, when running the same algorithm, `red` takes more (CPU) time than `blue` to get the same results. The outputs of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on the two machines is (for all four cores):

**Blue**

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Extreme CPU X9650  @ 3.00GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 1998.000
cache size  : 6144 KB
```

**Red**

```
processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU           @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 7
cpu MHz     : 2403.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
```

So, the results seem somehow related to the frequency as given in the `model name` row, while the value in `cpu MHz` seems to counter this trend. How should I interpret these data? How is it possible that the single core power of `blue` is lower than the single core power of `red` and yet the overall power of `blue` is higher? Could someone redirect me to an article explaining the phenomenon?

Thank you
Tunnuz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should heed the frequency given in the "Model name" field. At the time you took this snapshot of the CPU info, Blue happened to be running with a lower multiplier, likely because it wasn't under any load.

Comment: Hello. Yes, I got to the same conclusion, but that's not very helpful. I would like to understand the reason of this disparity.

Comment: It might be that it's lowering the frequency to save power, but I think `/proc/cpuinfo` usually shows the maximum frequency (edit: I was wrong, it doesn't do this). Try having a look around `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/` or `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/` and you should be able to find the list of available frequencies.

Comment: A little more info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=753473

Comment: Good, the detail about frequency scaling solved my doubt.